# Trying to change dynamically a context.clip(); in a HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, loops, canvas, drawimage

I'm trying to to change dynamically a context.clip(); in a HTML5 canvas, drawing a shape with different values from an array. The idea is to get different parts of a board-game illuminated one after the other, clipping a darker version of the board to see just a square of the clearer version.

That's the code I'm struggling with, based in other questions from this very site, but I really cannot find the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>HTML5 Trivial</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var strings = new Array();
strings[0] = "context.moveTo(134,487);context.lineTo(169,435);context.lineTo(200,449);context.lineTo(172,508);";
strings[1] = "context.moveTo(102,461);context.lineTo(142,414);context.lineTo(169,434);context.lineTo(133,485);";
strings[2] = "context.moveTo(71,434);context.lineTo(120,394);context.lineTo(143,414);context.lineTo(99,461);";
strings[3] = "context.moveTo(49,403);context.lineTo(101,370);context.lineTo(121,394);context.lineTo(70,435);";
strings[4] = "context.moveTo(19,340);context.lineTo(78,320);context.lineTo(99,370);context.lineTo(48,404);context.lineTo(31,375);";
strings[5] = "context.moveTo(172,507);context.lineTo(198,449);context.lineTo(231,458);context.lineTo(211,522);";
strings[6] = "context.moveTo(259,531);context.lineTo(267,466);context.lineTo(230,460);context.lineTo(213,521);";
strings[7] = "context.moveTo(257,531);context.lineTo(266,468);context.lineTo(300,470);context.lineTo(334,466);context.lineTo(347,531);context.lineTo(302,534);";

var images = new Array();

function draw(i){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'board_dark.jpg';
    img.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }
    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].onload = function() {
        eval(strings[Math.floor(Math.random()*6)]);
        context.closePath();
        context.clip();
        context.drawImage(images[i],0,0);
        i = i + 1;
        window.setTimeout(function(){draw(i)},100);
    }
    images[i].src = 'board.jpg';
}

</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="draw(0);">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1024" height="1024"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I coding terribly? I've been changing ways of writing, trying not to use the eval(), etc., without success...

Thank you for your help, as always!

Ramon

PD- Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is really really strange. I've redone some of it to give you a better idea of how to go about coding this (without using eval, for one!)

http://jsfiddle.net/p6tXv/

Now there is a general function that will draw from a list of points that you give it (they are the same points you supplied).

You almost certainly don't want to use clip and a dark image, instead you should be drawing over the board with semi-transparent black.

I wrote the code in such a way that it will black out the spots. If you want to black out everything except the spots then you will have to write a pat that is a little more complex, but it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I need to black out everything except the spots because the idea is to give the sensation of the spots glowing alternatively, but I'll try after your code. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment on the coding style; the use of eval() to call your context.moveTo logic is all kinds of bad. Check Google for various reasons on "why eval is bad"; it's been mentioned elsewhere numerous times.

Instead of storing commands, store the coordinates as polygon-style objects, and iterate through the points in order to achieve the desired result.

I realize that this could be a simple demo written to illustrate a specific purpose, but if you're sharing the code at all, then you'll be sharing bad code. Consider revising.